# Toshiba Satellite problem with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: toshiba-satellite

I was trying to load Ububntu 16,04 on my old laptop Toshiba Satellite A105 with new SSD Disk.
Installation guide don't see the disk. I updated BIOS - didin't help. 
After that i was trying to instal this same edition of Ubuntu on old disk. Installation was finished but after the system start the display is flashing with comunicate that language i chose (Polish) is not supported... I can't move foreward. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can choose english at first,

to go through the installation and then

after you are ready install the Polish language support,

either over the package management gui or over the apt utility on the commandline.

Was your new SSD Recognised by the BIOS of Your Toshiba Satelite Notebook?